# How does DuckDB handle Sparse tables?

Tags: duckdb

We are evaluating embedding duckdb in our applications. We deal with a lot of tables where the columns will be around 60-70 % sparse most of the time. Does duckdb fill them with default null values or does it support sparsity internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>At the moment, DuckDB does not support sparsity internally. But its something that we are considering.</s>

Update, 2023:

We have compression now that efficiently suppresses NULL storage using only a single bit. So this should now be greatly improved. –

Comment: This response is more than a year old. Any updates on this?

Comment: We are working on compressed storage which should address this right now. No ETA though.

Comment: more years have passed, this question pops up a lot. Any updates?

Comment: We have compression now that efficiently suppresses NULL storage using only a single bit. So this should now be greatly improved.